# Is it Makru to uncovered food?

Tags: food, reference-request

I heard that if things aren’t covered for a time or whole night one should avoid it. From what I remember it was said by someone close to me. I cannot find any source. Is it said by prophet Muhammad (PBUH)?

Comment: There are in fact ahadith recommending covering cups etc. for the night. And I've lately read an article supporting this as the taste of water for example changes if it was uncovered for the night in your room. Sadly I forgot the details and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Some ahadith out of them are:

- > Cover vessels, waterskins, close the doors and extinguish the lamps, for the Satan does not loosen the waterskin, does not open the door and does not uncover the vessels. And if one amongst you fails to find (something) to cover it well, he should cover it by placing (a piece of) wood across it. Qutaiba did not mention the closing of the doors in the hadith transmitted by him.
  > ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/36/120))
- > Cover the vessels and tie the waterskin, for there is a night in a year when pestilence descends, and it does not pass an uncovered vessel or an untied waterskin but some of that pestilence descending into it. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/36/129))
- > “The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) commanded us to cover our vessels, tie up our water skins and turn over our vessels.” ([Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1277720))